# Fill in the table values in the foreign key

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have two tables `Table1` and `Table2`, each with two columns: `Id, Name`.

Tables are filled with some data. I want to create a new table with the columns: `Id, T1_Id, T2_Id`, where `T1_Id` and `T2_Id` are foreign keys to `Table1` and `Table2` respectively.

How to create the table **as quickly as possible** to fill it with all the values and `T1_Id`, `T2_Id` already contained in the tables Table1 and Table2?

For example:

**Table 1:**

```
Id      Name
 1      T1N1
 2      T1N2
 3      T1N3
```

**Table 2:**

```
Id      Name
 1      T2N1
 2      T2N2
```

**Result table**;

```
Id    T1_Id   T2_Id
 1      1       1
 2      2       1
 3      3       1
 4      1       2
 5      2       2
 6      3       2
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `cross join`:

```
select row_number() over (order by (select null)) as id,
       t1.id as t1_id, t2.id as t2_id
into result
from table1 t1 cross join table2 t2;
```

This assumes that you don't actually care about the ordering of the `id` column in the result table.  If you do, you can do:

```
select row_number() over (order by t1.id, t2.id) as id,
       t1.id as t1_id, t2.id as t2_id
into result
from table1 t1 cross join table2 t2;
```

The first version is faster, because the second will actually do a sort.

Comment: The results isn't a table, just a two dimensional array.

Answer (score 2):

Use `CROSS JOIN` to get the Cartesian product of `Table 1` and `Table 3`.

Try this

```
select row_number() over(order by T2_Id,T1_Id) as Id,
       T1_Id ,
       T2_Id  
From [Table 1] A
CROSS JOIN [Table 3] B
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, "T1N1"});
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] {2, "T1N2"});
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] {3, "T1N3"});


            DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
            dt3.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            dt3.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

            dt3.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, "T2N1"});
            dt3.Rows.Add(new object[] {2, "T2N2"});

            DataTable results = new DataTable();
            results.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            results.Columns.Add("T1_Id", typeof(int));
            results.Columns.Add("T2_Id", typeof(int));

            int id = 1;
            foreach (DataRow row3 in dt3.AsEnumerable())
            {
                foreach (DataRow row1 in dt1.AsEnumerable())
                {
                    results.Rows.Add(new object[] { id++, row3.Field<int>("Id"), row1.Field<int>("Id") });
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```